# « Figurer » pour signifier « trouver la solution » etc. ?

Tags: sens, anglicismes

Peut-on confirmer si l'emploi du verbe [*figurer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/figurer) pour signifier *trouver la solution*, (arriver à) *comprendre* etc. est un anglicisme et le cas échéant s'il est courant ? Peut-on présenter une autre source que [celle-ci](http://www.visezjuste.uottawa.ca/pages/vocabulaire/ang_decouvrez_les_anglicismes.html) qui identifie cette difficulté et confirme ce qu'on a affirmé ?

Comment: Je connais depuis longtemps  l'expression *je n'arrive pas à me figurer la solution* dans le sens de *je n'arrive pas à me représenter, à trouver la solution*. Difficile de dire si c'est un anglicisme, puisque *figurer* dans le sens de *représenter* est correct selon la source que vous citez. En revanche, je ne connnaissais pas l'expression *figurer la solution*.

Comment: I think French "figurer" (verb) means something like "to appear (in a story etc)."

Comment: Ce n'est qu'une acception parmi beaucoup d'autres. Et ne répond pas du  tout à la question.

Comment: @Damien Voir aussi l'autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40452/19187) à ce sujet.

Comment: Hi! The question asks whether _figurer_ used for _figuring out_ a problem is borrowed from English and if this is used frequently. The second part asks if one can find another source than the one linked which confirms this is a loan from English and basically whether figurer and to figure (out) are "false friends" constructs here. As it stands your answer is off. If you meant that it does not mean "to find the solution" because it means something else, this is insufficient, as words will have many meanings, plus note I linked twice in the post, with a dictionary entry for _figurer_ etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ce n'est pas du tout courant, au moins en France (je ne sais pas pour le Canada). Quand j'ai lu le titre de cette question, je me suis demandé le rapport entre « figurer » et « trouver la solution » et je n'ai compris qu'en pensant à l'anglais *figure*.

On peut le confirmer en vérifiant que ce sens n'apparaît pas dans les dictionnaires, par exemple le [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/figurer) (très détaillé mais un peu vieux) ou le [*Larousse*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/figurer/33661) (plus récent mais plus succinct).

Le verbe pronominal a un sens un peu différent : *se figurer* une affirmation, c'est s'imaginer que cette chose est vraie. Dans ce sens, *se figurer* sous-entend en général que l'affirmation est fausse. Quand on se figure quelque chose, cela veut dire qu'on imagine la représentation de cette chose. Cela ne marche pas vraiment pour la solution d'un problème.

> Je me figure le cheval d'Henri IV. Dans mon imagination, il est blanc.
>
> Je me figurais une solution compliquée, avec des équations à n'en plus finir. En fait c'était 3.
>
> Je me figurais que la solution était très compliquée. En fait elle s'avéra simple.

Comment: Dans les cas de l'utilisation de l'imparfait il est vrai que souvent ce qui est annoncé comme étant figuré est aussitôt confirmé comme inexact mais ce n'est pas une règle. Par exemple ce n'est jamais le cas si l'adverbe « bien » est utilisé : « Je me figurais bien que c'était une histoire comme ça. ». Il n'est pas nécessaire non plus d'utiliser un adverbe : « Il se le figurait depuis longtemps et un jours on le lui a confirmé.», « Je me figurais qu'il y avait une trappe secrète, c'est bien ça ? ». Assez souvent il n'y a pas de confirmation du tout : « Je me figurais la joie d'Alain. ».

Answer (score 3):

Au Canada Français c'est courant comme expression.

***Figurer*** est l'utilisation de l'Anglicisme ***To figure***.

A voir cet [exemple](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/dix-mots-danglais-deformes/);

***To figure : devenu figurer, synonyme de réfléchir, trouver une solution. « Donne-moi dix minutes, je vais figurer quelque chose. »***

Le [site](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/dix-mots-danglais-deformes/) donne une belle explication sur le pourquoi:

*Noyés dans une mer anglophone, les Québécois ont pris l’habitude de déformer des mots anglais pour leur donner une allure française. Ainsi, certains mots comme bad trip sont devenus dans la langue parlée d’imaginatifs verbes du premier groupe. Un phénomène qui a donné naissance à des tournures de phrase étonnantes comme : « J’ai assez badtrippé hier soir. »*

Comment: Dans la langue parlée je l'ai certainement entendu mais je le trouve d'un registre très familier. C'est très subjectif mais pour moi _raqué, slaquer, charger et surtout checker_ sont bien plus courants et moins marqués que les autres dans la liste. Je trouve _choker, figurer, badlucké_ plutôt marqués et _déwrenché_ complètement relâché/caricatural.